# How to evaluate the value of derivative at a point in Python using SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy

I am learning SymPy which is a useful tool for doing complicated mathematics in Python. I wrote the following code to calculate the derivative of a function:

```
x = sympy.symbols('x')
f = x**2
dx_f = diff(f)
print(dx_f)
```

This, rightly, gives me the output as:

> 2*x

However, if I try to evaluate the derivative at a point:

```
print dx_f(2.0)
```

The kernel raises the following error:

> TypeError: 'Mul' object is not callable

How do I get around this error and what exactly is a 'Mul' Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to do it:

1. The quickest (in terms of writing code, but the slowest in terms of computation speed), but less reliable, using the `subs` method:

```
dx_f.subs(x, 2)
```

2. using the `evalf` method:

```
dx_f.evalf(subs={x: 2.0})
```

3. Using `lambdify`: this is preferred if you need to calculate functions using Numpy arrays:

```
f = lambdify([x], dx_f)
f(2.0)
```

A note about the type of number returned by each methods:

- `subs` might return numbers of type `Integer`, `Float`, `Rational` (these are SymPy type for numbers), depending on the expression and the value to substitute.
- `evalf` always returns a number of type `Float`.
- `lambdify` (used like in the example above) returns Python's number `int` or `float`, depending on the expression and the value to substitute.

Comment: This is great, thank you for this. I tried all three methods and all three worked. I still don't understand what an 'Mul' object is though

Comment: SymPy expressions are mainly composed of `Add` objects (addition), `Mul` objects (multiplications) and `Pow` objects (power). In short, that error is informing you that a multiplication cannot be used as a function. Please, mark this answer as the solution to your question if it satisfy your needs.